# Is there any difference between e, é and è ?

Tags: diacritiques, alphabet

Is there any difference between e, é and è ?

**Example**

> - société and societe,
> - première and premiere.

Do they have the same meaning?

Comment: "Societe" and "premiere" don't exist in French. You are talikng about French aren't you? Only *société* and *première* exist.

Comment: @Laure do they sounds any meaning for é and è ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Wikipedia has articles about accents, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent, well for something more specific  to French you have to click on the tabs for French.

Comment: I don't really understand either. "societe" and "premiere" just don't exist in French as Laure wrote. And if you see two words that are exactly the same, except an accent, so they aren't the same. You can't omit an accent. "Dîtes" is the conjugated form of "dire" with "vous" ("vous dîtes" = "you say"), when "dites" is the feminine and plural form of the past participle "dit" ("elles sont dites" = "they are said/told"). And note that e, é and è aren't pronounce the same way either. And you forgot ê and ë in the list. https://jakubmarian.com/french-e-e-e-e-e-whats-the-difference/

Comment: Just consider that é e è are 3 different characters, exactly the same than i and o. As stéphane said in his answer, porte and porté are 2 different words with 2 different meanings ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the two examples you gave would still be understood the same way without the accents, you must put them.

> Is there any difference between e, é and è ?

Most of time yes :

- une porte → a door
- porté(e) → handled, sustained,…
- une portée → a litter
- …
- rêve → dream
- rêvé → dreamt/dreamed
- il revêt → he put on clothe

Be also aware than "a" and "à" are two very different words ;)

Comment: The accent modify the prononciation on E but not on A or U